# create tag comment system in android same as facebook

Tags: android

**create tag comment system in android same as facebook.**
In comment section if we insert @ and type then show list of friend. and choose one friend. I want this type of comment system same as facebook.

Comment: Add a TextWatcher on the EditText (or AutoCompleteTextView) and monitor the input text. If you encounter '@', trigger a service call or get the relevant matches from the database.

Comment: please explain with example or code thanks

Comment: "please explain with example or code thanks" i.e. I'm too lazy or just can't do this thing myself so will issue demands and want to use someone as a free coding service.

Comment: First try it yourself, post what you had tried then people will help you. This will be helpful for you to start : http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/using-textwatcher-in-android.html, https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set a TextWatcher which will get triggered whenever text changes in your EditText. Then, you can use a Regex after an @ is found to see if there is any @name followed by a space. If there is, you can make another UI element pop up which shows a ListView of friends which match the particular Regex. Here is an example which I came up with:

```
// Declare listening as a member variable
    commentInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            // Listen until space
            String text = charSequence.toString();
            if (text.contains("@")) {
                listening = true;
                int index = text.split("@").length;
                String textToSearchFor = text.split("@")[index];
                // Use textToSearchFor to search for friends,
                // and if you get results then set a UI element
                // to appear: listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // on click of ListView element, stop listening
            } else if (text.substring(0, text.length() - 1).equals(" ")) {
                // If the latest character is a space, then stop listening
                listening = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: @user2002721 Please mark my answer as correct if it worked. Thanks.